# How to simplify n(C∩A'∩B')? Demorgan's Law?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i know by demorgan's law it becomes:

n(C∩(AUB)')

after this, in the book they turned this into:

n(C) - n(C∩(AUB))

i know what happens after this but i didn't get that last step. I tried to think about it logically without reaching anywhere. if anyone could provide both algebraic and logical approaches i will be thankful :)

Comment: What does the book mean by n(C)? Is it the number of members of C?

Comment: yes its the same as o(C)

Answer (score 0):

$C \iff (C\wedge(A\vee B)) \vee (C\wedge \neg(A\vee B))$

Got it? Try to visualize the venn diagram.

Comment: thanks :D i'd like to know more though.

Answer (score 0):

For any sets $C,X$ we have $C=(C\cap X)\cup (C$ \ $X).$ And the sets  $C\cap X,\; C$ \ $X$ are disjoint.

With $X=A\cup B,$ and with $C,X$ being subsets of some set $S,$ and $X'=S$ \ $X,$ we have $$C \backslash X=C\cap X'.$$

Since $C\cap X$ and $C$ \ $X$ are disjoint we have

$n(C\cap X)+n(C \cap X')=n(C\cap X)+n(C$ \ $X))=n(\;(C\cap X)\;\cup \;(C$ \ $X)\;)=n(C).$